# Mysql Insert data to table with duplicate data except one field

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, duplicates

I am developing a classroom website.

There is a form to insert student profile/data into the database table `student`.

This site has 5 class groups, IDs as `id= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Inserting data to database table succeeds.

But I have a question: Each student must be under classroom `1 and 2`, so when we insert data I need the database to automatically create two database results for each times, both results all field are same data except `classgroup_id`, i mean one result must `classgroup_id=1` and second result must be `classgroup_id=2`, i need mysql automatically generated this for when add each student... any idea.?

**this is my table structure**

- student_id  (int) AI
- name
- email
- classgroup_id  (default value=1)
- user_id

**this is my php code for insert data to table**

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "student SET user_id = '" . (int)$this->user->getId() . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "',  email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "'");
```

thanks... *i have only a medium level php knowledge*

Comment: you are inserting `student_id`? you don't have to insert AI fields.

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak... sorry that a mistake, i dnt insert student_id, mysql automatic  generate student_id for each student, i edited my question.... thanks

Comment: What is your primary key there?

Comment: student_id is primary key.. with Auto increment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassGroups are in table or just static numbers?

If they are just static numbers, then i think simpliest way is to do another insert with duplicated data. For example for both rows should be:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "student SET user_id = '" . (int)$this->user->getId() . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "',  email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "'");

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "student SET user_id = '" . (int)$this->user->getId() . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "',  email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', classgroup_id =2");
```

If they are in some table, then you can do insert with one insert(code will be shorter) but with different insert syntax then yours. For example your ClassGroup table is just ClassGroups:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "student (user_id, name, email, ClassGroup_id)
select " . (int)$this->user->getId() . ", '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "',  '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "',ClassGroup_id from ClassGroups where ClassGroup_id=1 or ClassGroup_id=2");
```

But i think it should be best if you do for each data(student, ClassGroup) different table and do relation table for them, it will not duplicate data and table student will be faster if you gather data from it by primary AI key and not by varchar type column name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PHP to do this... Pure SQL pseudosolution:

`INSERT INTO student (student_id name, email) SELECT name, email from student where classgroup_id = ?`

If you construct a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and leave a comment as to where to find said fiddle, I'd be happy to tweak the query for your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the record in temporary table first and then do the operations .. try it

```
//get last insertId
$last_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$new_id      = $last_insert_id +1;    


$query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE your_primary_key =  $last_insert_id;

         UPDATE tmp SET your_primary_key= $new_id,classgroup_id  = 2 WHERE your_primary_key = $last_insert_id;

         INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE your_primary_key = new_id";
$this->db->query($query);
```

Hope you get some idea

Comment: but my classgroup_id not primary key... i need classgroup_id only different from first result, 1 and 2... even this data 1 and 2 just a numeric number no problem... thanks

Comment: i set classgroup_d default value 1, so each time insert data classgroup_d field already have data 1, but i need a duplicate result also. that result classgroup_id value will be 2... thats it

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplicate entries for students, you can make another table in which you link the students to their classes.

For example:

**Students**

- student_id (primary key)
- name
- email
- user_id (if still needed...)

**Classgroups**

- classgroup_id (primary key)
- classgroup_name

**StudentsPerClassgroup**

- student_id (foreign key)
- classgroup_id (foreign key)